# WorkItemHttpClient - TFS work item not found or not permission to read it

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

Please find the below Wiql query. (Get all work items from a date - to date)

```
 @"SELECT *  FROM WorkItems  WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '" + _teamProjectName + "'  and( [System.ChangedDate] >= '" + fromDate + "' and [System.ChangedDate] <= '" + toDate + "')  ORDER BY [System.AssignedTo]"
```

I am getting all the work items from this query as per below code. (Please let me know if the query is correct) . But whenever I try to call this function `GetWorkItemsAsync` I get an error -

> TFS work item 'xyz' does not exist or you don't have permission to
>   read it

Essentially the `fromDate` is the start of the week, `toDate` is the end of the week.

```
 using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>())
            {
                //execute the query to get the list of work items in the results
                WorkItemQueryResult workItemQueryResult = workItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql).Result;

                IEnumerable<WorkItemReference> workItemRefs = workItemQueryResult.WorkItems;


                List<DateTime> weekDatesToGetWorkItems = weekDates();


                foreach (var item in weekDatesToGetWorkItems)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        int skip = 0;
                        const int batchSize = 100;

                        do
                        {
                            workItemRefs = workItemQueryResult.WorkItems.Skip(skip).Take(batchSize);
                            if (workItemRefs.Any())
                            {
                                //Exception here
                                List<WorkItem> workItems = workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(workItemRefs.Select(wir => wir.Id), this.GetFieldNames(), item).Result;
                                }
                        }
                        while (workItemRefs.Count() == batchSize);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
//// Always gives an exception for one of the workItem "TFS work item xyz does not exist or you don't have permission to read it"
                    }

                }
}
```

**Question 1:** 
Any idea how the above exception can be debugged or resolved?

**Question 2:** 
I already tried getting workitem data with `GetWorkItemAsync` by passing single workitemId. This works but the data which I get is not synced with the latest data, it always gives me data till prior week. Is there a proper way to get the latest one?

Any help over this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer to my Second question. Seems that i was doing a silly mistake with the time part.

I added the timestamp value  and now I was able to get the latest data.

```
   List<WorkItem> workItems = workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(workItemRefs.Select(wir => wir.Id), this.GetFieldNames(),
 item.Add(new TimeStamp(23,59,59))).Result;
 //// Adding timestamp worked here.
```

So next time if you are stuck with something which plays with dates never ignore the Time part. (Silly but always goes unnoticed).

Happy coding!!
cheers!